# I need to create dynamic interface for an activity in Kotlin

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I'm creating an user profile page .I created some buttons text fragment etc.But If I would try on the different screen .It is not looking like i want.Are not there some any easy way?
User_Profile_Page.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textDirection="locale"
    tools:context=".pages.User_Profile_Page"

    >
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/unichatLabelMainPage2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="685dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/aladin"
            android:text="UNICHAT"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#F19B1A"
            android:textSize="48sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.047"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.008" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="117dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.534"
            tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_followers_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="11"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.708"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/folllowers_textView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_follow_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="123"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.974"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/follow_textView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_post_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="12"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/post_textView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/folllowers_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="29dp"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:text="Followers"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.759"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.264" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/post_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="29dp"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:text="Posts"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.478"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.264" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/follow_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="29dp"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:text="Follow"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.264" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/edit_profile_button"
            android:layout_width="105dp"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:text="Edit Your Profile"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.609"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.855" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/share_profile_button"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:text="Share"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.855" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/posts_Button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="450dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="_________________________________________________________"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Posts_Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="248dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="455dp"
            android:onClick="posts_button"
            android:text="Posts"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.235"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.351" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/posts_Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="248dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="455dp"
            android:onClick="liked_button"
            android:text="Liked"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.776"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1.0" />


    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.002"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/user_graph"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[low screen size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZcSD.png)
[high screen size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rk2C.jpg)

I saw something dimen.xml etc. But how it's working I didn't understand.Are not there easy way? or More understandable.Can you explain please?

Comment: You're using a lot of explicit, hard-coded values for layout heights, like `            android:layout_height="35dp"` - use `wrap_content` instead.

Comment: I know but  I want to dynamic text size , dynamic button size etc . for different screen sizes

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "dynamic" (interface / text size / button size / etc)

Comment: And have you reviewed [the documentation on this topic](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/support-different-screen-sizes) already?

Comment: I mean for dynamic.Example button size will change for different screens .Small screens equals small button size .Ratio I mean

Comment: Did you review the documentation I linked to already?